# How to turn off autocomplete in PgAdmin4?

Tags: pgadmin-4

How do you turn off the autocomplete/help-tips in PgAdmin4? They're driving me insane.

Every cursor movement and keypress causes a "Loading..." overlay to appear, which either displays nothing or displays a useless "help" dropdown, in case I want to replace my, say, SELECT keyword, with one of a hundred other SQL statements.

I've scanned the File->Preferences option, and disabled all "auto-complete" options I could find, but that hasn't disabled it.

Comment: Thanks for asking. It has been driving me around the bend, too. Every time I tried to tab over it inserted "ABORT".

Comment: That was one of the most poorly implemented things I've ever seen. Thank you for asking this.

Answer (score 7):

From the menu found by following "File > Preferences > Query Tool > Auto Complete", I found that toggling "Autocomplete on key press" successfully turned this off. However, I had to close my query tool window and open a new one for it to take effect.

[image: Auto complete settings screen]

I'm using pgAdmin 4 6.12

Comment: I'd found the preferences item but didn't know about having to use a new window. All good now. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

#### Answering Your Question

1. Open up the menu **File** and click on **Preferences**.
2. Scroll down to the **Query Tool** section and there select the **Editor** option.

   [image: image of the Query Tool | Editor settings]
3. In the settings for **Query Tool | Editor** set the option **Plain text mode** to **TRUE**:

   [image: Setting Plain text mode to true image]

#### Verifying The Setings

When you open a query window you can observe the following behaviour.

1. Plain text mode = false

   [image: image showing autocomplete working when "Plain text mode" is set to false]
2. Plan text mode = true

   [image: image showing autocomplete not working when "Plain text mode" is set to "true"]

This should speed up your queries.

Comment: I saw the `Plain text mode` setting and tried that. Unfortunately, that goes too far and disables everything useful, like code coloring/highlighting. I don't have anything against the editor in general. I just want to disable the help dropdown.

Comment: It seems like it's all or nothing. Sorry.

Comment: Please see Ben Hancock's answer. It works to just disable Autocomplete on key press. Keeping syntax coloration is important.